# How to pass variables as arguments of a function in a vim script

Tags: vim, macvim

I am trying to pass some global variables to a function in a vim script. However, I end up receiving the variable names, not the actual variable values once they are passed to the function. Here is a simple case:

```
let g:my_var_a = "melon"
let g:my_var_b = "apple"

" Define the main function
function! MyFunc(myarg1, myarg2)
    echom "Arguments: " . a:myarg1 . ", " . a:myarg2
endfunction

" Link the function to a command
command! -nargs=* HookMyFunc call MyFunc(<f-args>)

" Link the command to a plug
nnoremap <unique> <Plug>MyHook :HookMyFunc g:my_var_a g:my_var_b<CR>

" Assign a key to the plug
nmap <silent> <leader>z <Plug>MyHook
```

So, if I do this: `nnoremap <unique> <Plug>MyHook :HookMyFunc melon apple<CR>`

I get the output of: `Arguments: melon apple`

and when I do this: `nnoremap <unique> <Plug>MyHook :HookMyFunc g:my_var_a g:my_var_b<CR>`

my output is `Arguments: g:my_var_a g:my_var_b`

What is the way to evaluate those variables as they are passed to the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to evaluate the line with `:execute` so it will become:

```
nnoremap <unique> <Plug>MyHook :execute 'HookMyFunc ' . g:my_var_a . ' ' . g:my_var_b<CR>
```

Think of this as building up a string and then evaluating(/executing) it.

For more help see: `:h :exe`